# Calculating time between text field interactions

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataset of text field interactions across several dozen users of my application across the span of several months. I'm trying to calculate the average time between keystrokes in pandas. The data look something like this:

```
timestamp                before_text     after_text
1453481138188                  NULL               a
1453481138600                     a              ab 
1453481138900                    ab             abc
1453481139400                   abc            abcd
1453484000000    Enter some numbers               1
1453484000100                     1              12
1453484000600                    12             123
```

`timestamp` contains the unix time that the user pressed the key, `before_text` is the what the text field contained before the user hit the key, and `after_text` is what the field looked like after the keystroke.

What's the best way to go about doing this? I know that's not as simple as doing something like:

```
(df["timestamp"] - df["timestamp"].shift()).mean()
```

because this will calculate a very large time difference on the boundary between two interactions. It seems like the best way to do this would be to pass some function of each row to `df.groupby` so that I can apply the above snippet to each row. If I had this `magic_function` I could do something like:

```
df.groupby(magic_function).apply(lambda x: x["timestamp"] - x["timestamp"].shift()).mean()
```

What's a good way to implement `magic_function`, or am I thinking about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it by calculating the text difference between 'before' and 'after'.  If the difference is greater than some threshold, then that is a new session.

It requires `from Levenshtein import distance as ld`.  I installed it via `pip` like so:

```
pip install python-levenshtein
```

Then:

```
from Levenshtein import distance as ld
import pandas as pd

# taking just these two columns and transposing and back filling.
# I back fill for one reason, to fill that pesky NA with after text.
before_after = df[['before_text', 'after_text']].T.bfill()

distances = before_after.apply(lambda x: ld(*x))

# threshold should be how much distance constitutes an obvious break in sessions.
threshold = 2
magic_function = (distances > 2).cumsum()

df.groupby(magic_function) \
  .apply(lambda x: x["timestamp"] - x["timestamp"].shift()) \
  .mean()

362.4
```

Comment: +1 Chosen as best answer because it avoids using a for loop and makes use of pandas' vectorized operations.

Comment: FYI, @PastyWhiteMike: `.apply()` is a `for` loop, not vectorized.

Comment: i guess you can use vectorized approach here: `df.groupby(magic_function).timestamp.diff().mean()`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem essentially is to identify when a given interaction stops and when another begins. Perhaps compute the difference between `timestamp`s, and if greater than a threshold, set a flag on which you can group.

```
thresh = 1e5
ts = (df['timestamp'] - df['timestamp'].shift()) > thresh
grp = [0]
for i in range(len(ts)):
    if ts.iloc[i]:
        grp.append(grp[-1] + 1)
    else:
        grp.append(grp[-1])
grp.append(grp[-1])
df['grouper'] = grp
```

Now you can simply group like so: `grouped = df.groupby('grouper')`, then subtract the `timestamp`s within the group, and compute the average difference.

I am trying to think of a way to avoid the loop, but till then try this and let me know how it goes.